# QTcpSocket does not emit connected()

Tags: qt5

I'm using QT5 and starting out with a basic Server/Client setup. I'm looking at going single threaded for both apps as there is no heavy processing on network data. Now, from everything I've read and researched here, when using asynchronous approach, you don't use waitForXXXX() otherwise it messes up all the signals and slots. The problem - On the client end, the connected() signal is either never emitted or never processed, even though the server consoles tells me that a new client has connected. I've been working on the same issue for 2 weeks now and couldn't find the exact same issue anywhere. I've stripped back both apps to the minimum and still no luck - also stripped out the UI part now - I just want see the console working. I have also tried switching to public slots and changing the signal/slot connection type and still have the same problem.

If you require code from the server, please let me know, but here is the basics of the client:

main.cpp

```
#include "QGameSocket.h"
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>

#include <windows.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    AllocConsole();
    freopen( "conin$", "r", stdin );
    freopen( "conout$", "w", stdout );
    freopen( "conout$", "w", stderr );

    QApplication a( argc, argv );
    QGameSocket* pSocket = new QGameSocket();

    return a.exec();
}
```

QGameSocket.h

```
#ifndef _QGAMESOCKET_H
#define _QGAMESOCKET_H

#include <QtNetwork/qtcpsocket.h>
#pragma comment ( lib, "Qt5Network.lib" )

class QGameSocket: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit QGameSocket( QObject* pParent = 0 );
    ~QGameSocket();

private slots:
    void __OnConnected();
    void __OnReadyRead();

private:
    QTcpSocket* m_pSocket;
};

#endif
```

QGameSocket.cpp

```
#include "QGameSocket.h"
#include <qdatastream.h>

QGameSocket::QGameSocket( QObject* pParent ) :  
    QObject( pParent )
{
    m_pSocket = new QTcpSocket();
    
    connect( m_pSocket, SIGNAL( connected() ), this, SLOT( __OnConnected() ) );
    connect( m_pSocket, SIGNAL( readyRead() ), this, SLOT( __OnReadyRead() ) );

    const QString strHost = "127.0.0.1";

    qDebug() << "Connecting to host ...";
    m_pSocket->connectToHost( strHost, 27015 );
}

QGameSocket::~QGameSocket()
{
    m_pSocket->deleteLater();
}

void QGameSocket::__OnConnected()
{
    qDebug() << "Successfully connected to host!";
}

void QGameSocket::__OnReadyRead()
{
    //handle messages
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Try to remove these unnecessary spaces inside SIGNAL and SLOT or even better - switch to modern syntax: `connect(m_pSocket, &QTcpSocket::connected, this, &QGameSocket::__OnConnected);`

Comment: Turns out that this is not the issue, but for my own knowledge, is there a situation that the modern syntax would work and the older (what I've used) wouldn't? Or is it just preferred?

Comment: Good topic coverage [here](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax). 

Personally, I prefer to use lambdas instead of short private slots like `__Onconnected`, which is not possible with the old syntax.

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured it out - I was using the release network library, not the debug library.
I changed:

```
#pragma comment ( lib, "Qt5Network.lib" )
```

to

```
#pragma comment ( lib, "Qt5Networkd.lib" )
```

Comment: It would be better to add libraries via QT variable in the project's .pro file: `QT += network`https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetwork-index.html